# Redirect content to a file in ascii encoding

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, less, windows-8.1

We're running `lessc` from the PowerShell like this:

```
lessc -x style.less > style.min.css
```

Unfortunately, `style.min.css` file is in `unicode` whereas we would like it to be in `ascii`. How can we force that encoding when writing the result to a file from PowerShell?

Interestingly, when we run the same command from a vanilla command prompt, the encoding is `ascii`.

Comment: "Unicode" is not an encoding.  What encoding are you getting? Are you getting a BOM?

Comment: I am getting a BOM. I'm also just reading [the about_redirection docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) which say, "When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use Unicode encoding." So, I'm close to a solution.

Comment: @SLaks Out of curiosity, what does you mean when you say that Unicode is not an encoding? Why not?

Comment: A character encoding is a scheme that converts a sequence of Unicode codepoints into bytes.  UTF8 and UTF16 are encodings.  See the relevant Wikipedia articles.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As a simple workaround, specify the output as a [command-line parameter](http://lesscss.org/usage/#command-line-usage-server-side-and-command-line-usage) instead of redirecting stdout:

```
lessc -x style.less style.min.css
```

Answer (score 1):

The [about_Redirection](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847746.aspx) say this about PowerShell redirection.

> When you are writing to files, the redirection operators use Unicode encoding... To redirect content to non-Unicode files, use the Out-File cmdlet with its Encoding parameter.

[Out-File](https://technet.microsoft.com/library/hh849882.aspx) works:

```
lessc -x style.less | Out-File style.min.css -Encoding ascii
```